# Swift Timers in Loop all fire at the same time instead of sequentially

Tags: swift, timer

I am using a Swift Timer which works fine until I try putting it into a loop. I start the timer and after it reaches zero the selector calls a method to invalidate the timer. I want this to be repeated for 3 times and have a counter that counts the number of iterations this goes through.

```
func start() {
    var interval = 0
    repeat {
       interval += 1
       print ("Interval \(interval)")
       timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self,    selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } while (interval <= 3)
    }
    @objc func fireTimer() {
        timeOn  -= 1
        if timeOn == 0 {
            print("timer done")
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

The output is:

Interval 1
Interval 2
Interval 3
timer done

It seems as if 3 timers are started simultaneously and then the timer.invalidate stops all of them. What I want is to have the timers start independently and run sequentially. Notice the repeat/while loop. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said:

> It seems as if 3 timers are started simultaneously and then the timer.invalidate stops all of them.

No. All three timers are running and when you call `invalidate` you're just invalidating the last one. Each time you set `timer`, you are discarding your reference to the prior one. Because you discarded your references to your first two timers, you now have no way to stop them. (Add a `print` statement in `fireTimer` and you will see the other two continue to fire after you cancel the one timer.) And because you invalidated on timer when `timeOn` was zero, the other two will keep firing, with `timeOn` now having negative values, and the `== 0` test will never succeed again.

Instead, you could let your timer handler routine to accept a parameter, the timer reference. That way each one would be able to invalidate itself.

E.g.

```swift
func start() {
    for interval in 0..< 3 {            // if you really want three timers, then for loop is easiest
        print ("Interval \(interval)")
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

@objc func fireTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
    print(Date(), "tick")

    timeOn -= 1
    if timeOn <= 0 {
        print("timer done")
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Now that is exceedingly confusing have multiple repeating timers all updating the same `timeOn` property. I changed the `if` test to be `<=` 0 to address that problem.

It begs the question why you would want multiple repeating timers firing at basically the same time. E.g. every second, `timeOn` is being reduced by three. Is that really the intent? Generally you would only want one repeating timer.

This process of scheduling a bunch of timers also begs the question of how you will cancel them when the object in question is deallocated. I guess you could keep an array of them, but it seems very convoluted way of doing it. The other approach is to use the block-based timer with `[weak self]` reference (to prevent strong reference cycle), and then each can check to see if `self` is `nil` and if so, invalidate itself:

```swift
func start() {
    for interval in 0..< 3 {            // if you really want three timers, then for loop is easiest
        print ("Interval \(interval)")
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
            guard let self = self else {
                timer.invalidate()
                return
            }

            self.fireTimer(timer, interval: interval)
        }
    }
}

func fireTimer(_ timer: Timer, interval: Int) {
    print(Date(), "tick", interval)

    timeOn -= 1
    if timeOn <= 0 {
        print("timer done")
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

But I am unclear why you would want multiple repeating timers at all.

---

You said:

> I don’t really want 3 timers. I want the timer block to run three times, sequentially.

Then just create a repeating timer that will run three times and then `invalidate` itself:

```swift
weak var timer: Timer?             // weak because when you schedule the timer, the RunLoop keeps a strong reference

deinit {
    timer?.invalidate()            // in case the timer is still running after you dismiss this object/controller
}

func start() {
    timer?.invalidate()            // in case you accidentally called this previously, cancel any prior timer (before you lose a reference to it)
    
    var counter = 0
    
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        counter += 1
        if counter >= 3 { timer.invalidate() }

        self?.doSomething(counter)  // do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

Key things to note:

1. I used single repeating timer.
2. I used closure based rendition with `[weak self]` to avoid the strong reference cycle of the selector-based rendition of `Timer`.
3. If you’d like to keep a reference to the timer so that you can `invalidate` it as soon as the parent object is deallocated, keep your own `weak` reference to it.
4. In `start`, I `invalidate` any prior timer, which is obviously unnecessary if you make sure that you call `start` once and only once. But, again, it is a solid defensive programming pattern to `invalidate` any prior timer before you replace any old reference with a new `Timer` reference.

Comment: I thanks for the reply. I don’t really want 3 timers. I want the timer block to run three times, sequentially.

Comment: Then it’s simplified a bit. I’ve edited my answer to include the “single repeating timer that fires three times” solution (including a few refinements that are prudent).

Comment: Thanks you for your detailed and thoughtful answer. It may help if I explain better what I am looking for. I want a count down timer that repeats. So the timer fires for 10 seconds (for example) then starts again and repeats for another 10 seconds for x number of repeats. The count down timer displays seconds remaining  and the current number of repeats. Note that I am using the word repeats here in a different context than the timer argument. Your last code above works, but for only the first 'repeat'.

Comment: OK, that helps understand why you were thinking of multiple timers. Still, though, if it’s going to immediately start counting down automatically, you would probably only have the one `Timer` instance, and just reset what you’re counting to. You could create a new instances, but unless you are waiting for user interaction before starting it again, that’s probably unnecessary complicated.

Comment: Thanks-You! My take-away from your comments lead me to focus on one timer and one instance. I now have it working! I learned a ton from your comments. Thanks again for your time.