# Swift: How to set different timer interval and repeat it?

Tags: swift, timer

I want to set a Timer which acting like this:
fire at 4 sec,
fire at 15 sec,
fire at 19 sec,
then all repeat again, which means another 4 sec, 15 sec, 19 sec sequence again.

I found related topics to this:

[Set a timer with variable intervals in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241413/set-a-timer-with-variable-intervals-in-swift)

[Swift Timers in Loop all fire at the same time instead of sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65755880/swift-timers-in-loop-all-fire-at-the-same-time-instead-of-sequentially)

but I still can't make them to fit my need.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Fire a counter every second and count how many time you enter in it and do desired action at 4 sec, 15 sec, 19 sec. At 19 s you reset your counter. Use a property of the object that create the timer to keep track of the count.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, I figure out how to do it: timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {[weak self] timer in counter += 1 if counter == 4 { self?.soundCycleStart() } if counter == 15 { self?.soundCycleStart() } if counter == 19 { self?.soundCycleStart() } if counter > 19 { counter = 0 } }) it may looks stupid, but it works. Thanks

Comment: I add no better or simplest idea. Good it can work.